# What is "ms-cxh-full://0.0.135.7"?

Tags: windows

When I enter this "ms-cxh-full: //0.0.135.7" into my browser and open the program, a black screen appears.
Is there any other way to close this black screen other than restarting my PC and what kind of program is it and what can it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ms-cxh-full:// link is the User OOBE Broker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a broken System link that shouldn't be accessible by users, but Microsoft messed up and left it in. If you don't recognize the protocol don't open it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the URL that you posted:

```
ms-cxh-full: //0.0.135.7
```

It started a black screen (as you said), but the screen disappeared after 2 seconds and the computer continued to function normally.

OS: `Windows 10.0.19043.1202`

Web browser: `Microsoft Edge 93.0.961.38`

Update your OS and change your web browser, and you'll have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing SHIFT + F10 or if you're on a laptop try SHIFT + FUNCTION + F10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.